# countdown timer is not working javascript

Tags: javascript, countdowntimer

I m trying to run this countdown timer but it's not working please help me
I try to generate a random number between two numbers and start timer but it's working please help me

```
  String.prototype.toHHMMSS = function () {
     var sec_num = parseInt(this, 10); // don't forget the second parm
     var hours = Math.floor(sec_num / 3600);
     var minutes = Math.floor((sec_num - (hours * 3600)) / 60);
     var seconds = sec_num - (hours * 3600) - (minutes * 60);

    if (hours < 10) {
        hours = "0" + hours;
    }
    if (minutes < 10) {
        minutes = "0" + minutes;
    }
    if (seconds < 10) {
        seconds = "0" + seconds;
    }
    var time = hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds;
    return time;
}

function getRandomArbitrary(min, max) {
  return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}

var count = getRandomArbitrary(21000,23000);

var counter = setInterval(timer, 1000);

function timer() {


    console.log(count);

    if (parseInt(count) <= 0) {
        clearInterval(counter);
        return;
    }
    var temp = count.toHHMMSS();
    count = (parseInt(count) - 1).toString();

    $('#timer').html(temp);
}
```

HTML code

```
<div id="timer"></div>
```

Comment: What do you mean, "not working", can you be more specific? What errors do you run into?

Comment: @aijaz try my answer you just missed a statement in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You have extended the string prototype with your conversion function, but you're not using a string (`count` is a number from the `getRandom...` method). Use a normal function instead, and it will work on more types:

```js
toHHMMSS = function (str) {
     var sec_num = parseInt(str, 10); // don't forget the second parm
     var hours = Math.floor(sec_num / 3600);
     var minutes = Math.floor((sec_num - (hours * 3600)) / 60);
     var seconds = sec_num - (hours * 3600) - (minutes * 60);

    if (hours < 10) {
        hours = "0" + hours;
    }
    if (minutes < 10) {
        minutes = "0" + minutes;
    }
    if (seconds < 10) {
        seconds = "0" + seconds;
    }
    var time = hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds;
    return time;
}

function getRandomArbitrary(min, max) {
  return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}

var count = getRandomArbitrary(21000,23000);

var counter = setInterval(timer, 1000);

function timer() {


    console.log(count);

    if (parseInt(count) <= 0) {
        clearInterval(counter);
        return;
    }
    var temp = toHHMMSS(count);
    count = (parseInt(count) - 1).toString();

    $('#timer').html(temp);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="timer"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try my code.

Your code problem is that you didn't convert `count.toHHMMSS();` this line into string when you call.

```js
String.prototype.toHHMMSS = function () {
     var sec_num = parseInt(this, 10); // don't forget the second parm
     var hours = Math.floor(sec_num / 3600);
     var minutes = Math.floor((sec_num - (hours * 3600)) / 60);
     var seconds = sec_num - (hours * 3600) - (minutes * 60);

    if (hours < 10) {
        hours = "0" + hours;
    }
    if (minutes < 10) {
        minutes = "0" + minutes;
    }
    if (seconds < 10) {
        seconds = "0" + seconds;
    }
    var time = hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds;
    return time;
}

function getRandomArbitrary(min, max) {
  return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}

var count = getRandomArbitrary(21000,23000);

var counter = setInterval(timer, 1000);

function timer() {


    console.log(count);

    if (parseInt(count) <= 0) {
        clearInterval(counter);
        return;
    }
    var temp = count.toString().toHHMMSS();
    count = (parseInt(count) - 1).toString();

    $('#timer').html(temp);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="timer"></div>
```